# switch/case within a switch/case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

The following appears in my WinProc:

```
if(message == WM_CREATE)
{
//Do WM_CREATE stuff
}

else
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch(wParam)
            {
                case VK_LEFT:
                {
                //declare new variable here
                D2D1_RECT_F bounds;
                HRESULT hr = pDemoApp->mpGeometryGroup->GetBounds(pDemoApp->mTransform, &bounds);
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with declaring and using variables this way?

I set up a breakpoint after I declare and use bounds (still within the scope) but I can't seem to find it in the 'Locals' window in the debugger. What is wrong?

I didn't want to spam the post with a bunch of unrelated code, but here is the full WinProc.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DemoApp::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
LRESULT result = 0;

if (message == WM_CREATE)
{
    LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
    DemoApp *pDemoApp = (DemoApp *)pcs->lpCreateParams;

    ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
        hwnd,
        GWLP_USERDATA,
        PtrToUlong(pDemoApp)
        );

    result = 1;
}
else
{
    DemoApp *pDemoApp = reinterpret_cast<DemoApp *>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
        ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
        hwnd,
        GWLP_USERDATA
        )));

    bool wasHandled = false;

    if (pDemoApp)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_SIZE:
            {
                UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
                UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
                pDemoApp->OnResize(width, height);
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

        case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
            {
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                pDemoApp->OnRender();
                ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL);
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            {
                D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = pDemoApp->mpRenderTarget->GetSize();
                static float angle = 0.0f;

                switch(wParam)
                {
                case VK_LEFT:
                    {

                        angle -= 90;

                        if(angle < -360)
                            angle = 0;

                        D2D1_RECT_F bounds;
                        HRESULT hr = pDemoApp->mpGeometryGroup->GetBounds(pDemoApp->mTransform, &bounds);

                            pDemoApp->mTransform = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(
                            angle,
                            D2D1::Point2F((bounds.right + bounds.left)/2, (bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2)
                            );

                            hr = hr;


                        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
                        break;
                        }

                case VK_RIGHT:
                    {
                        angle += 90;

                        if(angle > 360)
                            angle = 0;

                        D2D1_RECT_F bounds;
                        pDemoApp->mpGeometryGroup->GetBounds(pDemoApp->mTransform, &bounds);

                            pDemoApp->mTransform = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(
                            angle,
                            D2D1::Point2F((bounds.right + bounds.left)/2, (bounds.bottom + bounds.top)/2)
                            );


                        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
                        break;
                    }

                case VK_DOWN:
                    {
                        pDemoApp->mTransform = pDemoApp->mTransform * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                            0.0f,
                            5.0f);

                        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                FLOAT xPos, yPos;

                xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
                yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

                BOOL contains = false;

                pDemoApp->mpGeometryGroup->FillContainsPoint(
                    D2D1::Point2F(xPos, yPos),
                    pDemoApp->mTransform,
                    &contains);

                if(contains)
                    MessageBoxA(hwnd, "Hooray!", NULL, NULL);

                D2D1_GEOMETRY_RELATION relation;

                pDemoApp->mpGeometryGroup->CompareWithGeometry(
                    pDemoApp->mpSecondGeometryGroup,
                    pDemoApp->mTransform,
                    0.001f,
                    &relation);

                if(relation == D2D1_GEOMETRY_RELATION_CONTAINS ||
                    relation == D2D1_GEOMETRY_RELATION_IS_CONTAINED ||
                    relation == D2D1_GEOMETRY_RELATION_OVERLAP)
                {
                    MessageBoxA(hwnd, "overlap or contains.", 0, 0);
                }


            }
            result = 0;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            result = 1;
            wasHandled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!wasHandled)
    {
        result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: Still within which scope?  The debugger may "fall out of the scope" containing bounds as soon as `GetBounds` returns, even if it pretends it's still finishing that line.  Put `hr = hr;` on the line after and see if that helps.

Comment: I put that after and it's still not showing up for some reason. I didn't want to bog down the post with other details, but I will post the entire code above (taking out the other WM messages). Check back in a second.

Comment: The only problem is variables not appearing in the locals window?  Are you in a release build?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have to hit the "right" key 9 times to do a complete circle instead of 8.  You probably want `if (angle >= 360) angle -= 360;`

Comment: Debug build. The only other odd thing is that in the locals window, if I expand hwnd, sometimes I will see a red exclamation point next to unused which says "CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated." The breakpoint was set on the GetBounds() line when I just saw that. I'm not getting the expected results in the program but I'm not sure if it is a problem with this code or a lack of understanding of Direct2D.

Comment: Expression cannot be evaluated because it's a uninitialized pointer, pointing at random memory, and the debugger can't figure out what it's pointing it.  That's perfectly normal.  Do the variables have the correct values when you mouse over them?

Comment: I tried mousing over angle and bounds and nothing pops up. angle doesn't appear in the locals window either, but it should, right? Something strange is happening. :(

Comment: Heap corruption is a possibility I hadn't considered...

Comment: In WinMain there is a call to: HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0); In the comments it says the program will terminate if there is a problem detected with the heap. I'm too much of a beginner to look into this, though. I thought the heap was only used for dynamic allocation using new.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say stack.  Although that's usually far more obvious than anything you've described.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in declaring variables that way, since you have specified a new scope for the `VK_LEFT` case. If you weren't declaring a separated scope, then variables would be visible yet possibly non-initialized which would be a problem. Note that you missed a few `breaks` by the way.